# Python logging to same file, different users

Tags: python, linux, logging, file-permissions

I am using the logging module of python.

In the case of unit tests (we use py.test) every time tests are launched, some log information goes to a certain file. In the integration server, everytime someone pushes code (we also use git :) we run the tests.

The problem is that once the file is created, by user A when user B tries to run the tests, the tests will fail as user B has no permission to write on the same file.

So far, we have changed the file permissions manually, but looks like a dirty solution. Also we though of creating a log file per user, but again, does not feel right.

Our code for the logging in the tests is

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
    format='%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s',
    datefmt='%m-%d %H:%M',
    filename='/tmp/py.test.log',
    filemode='w')
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
log.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
```

Is there a way to avoid this problem? Maybe using filemode = 'a' could do it, but lets assume I want a new file everytime (to be honest this is more curiosity that a real problem, still I want to do it right)

Thanks :)

Comment: how about adding the username to the filename, so each user gets their own separate copy?

Comment: @MarcB as I said in the question "Also we though of creating a log file per user, but again, does not feel right." I just want to know if we can use the same log for everyone.

Comment: Increment the log file name every test?

Comment: see [Logging to a single file from multiple processes](http://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html) though a single file doesn't seem useful in your case unless you log to multiple destinations

Comment: @AlexL Again, and as I said on the question "Also we though of creating a log file per user, but again, does not feel right." Creating different log files is somehow discarded.

Comment: Could you keep the current test's log file in memory or a temp directory, then append to the main log file? This might solve both your problems - access problems, and multiple tests at once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like the logging process is trying to write on top of an existing file that's owned by another user. Here is a procedure for allowing group access for the group `loggroup` to the directory `logdir`.

1. Make the containing directory group-writable.

   ```
   $ chgrp loggroup logdir
   $ chmod g+w logdir
   ```
2. Set the **setgid** bit on `logdir`.  That makes new files in `logdir` always owned by the group.  Otherwise, new files are owned by the creator's group.

   ```
   $ chmod g+s logdir
   ```
3. Ensure all logging users belong to `loggroup`.

   ```
   $ usermod -a -G loggroup myuser
   ```
4. Ensure all writing processes have the right umask so they can make newly created files group-writable.

   ```
   $ umask 0002
   ```
5. Now all members of the `loggroup` group can create files in `logdir` and overwrite each other's files.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but as I said in the question "So far, we have changed the file permissions manually, but looks like a dirty solution. Also we though of creating a log file per user, but again, does not feel right" So yes, we already did the file permission changes, I just wonder if it is possible to do something directly from the code (and I do not mean executing those commands from python). Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the git hash as part of the filename. Then if there were weird messages in the log, you know which version caused it.

Another possibility is to run the tests from a different directory or even in a chroot.

Changing the permissions or removing the file might also work, but you still get a messy log file if the tests are run by two or more users at the same time.

You could also make a logger that doesn't log anything if you don't care about the content, or log to a database or... really the right/best answer depends on the situation

Comment: It is a good point that if two users run the tests at the same time the file will look weird, to say the least.

Answer (score -3):

```
import os
os.chmod("/some/location/file.type", 0777)
```

You can do this for the created file I guess. where 0777 is the permissions in octa. you can change it to whatever you want.

Comment: This doesn't work because the logging module appears to not actually write the file until the program is completed, so any chmod call will result in file not found.